# Chamar aplicação asp.net através de página HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, script

Tenho uma aplicação a qual não posso alterar o código fonte que gera pedidos de compras. Pra cada pedido é armazenado um html com os dados da solicitação. Quero implementar esse html com o seguinte:
Ao abrir o html, incorporar nele uma página simples em asp.net que vai trazer informações e um link correspondente ao número daquela solicitação.

O template do `HTML` gerado atualmente é o seguinte:

```
<TABLE width="100%" bordercolorlight="#000000" border="1">
 <TBODY>
   <TR>
      <!--TD style="WIDTH: 112px">
          <P align=left><img border="0" src=!wf_link!images/logo.jpg></P>
      </TD-->
      <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; width: 18%;">
          <img style="width:auto; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; height:auto;" src=!wf_link!images/logo.jpg>
      </td>

      <td style="WIDTH: 866px; TEXT-ALIGN: center">
          <p><font size="3"><b>SOLICITAÇÃO DE COMPRAS Nr. %NUMSC% (Filial %FILIAL%)</b></font> // campo que preciso obter na minha consulta ao banco
      </td>

      <td style="WIDTH: 300px">
          <dl>
              <div align="left">
                  <dt><font><b>Cód. Aprov.:</b></font>
                      <FONT color=#000000 face="Verdana">
                          <SPAN class=style7 style="font-weight: 400">%CAMPO2%</span>
                      </FONT>
                  </dt>
                  <dd>
                  <dt><b><font align="left">Nome:</font></b>
                      <FONT color=#000000 face="Verdana">
                          <SPAN class=style7 style="font-weight: 400">%CAMPO3%</span>
                      </FONT>
                  </dt>
              </div>
          </dl>
      </td>

  </TR>
```

A página asp.net que desejo incorporar no código:

```
<script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(Object Src, EventArgs E)
        {

            string host = "****";
            string usuario = "****";
            string senha = "****";
            string banco = "****"; 


  string strSQL = "SELECT codigo, arquivolink from MinhaTabela"; // Aqui eu preciso dar um where pegando o campo %NUMSC% do HTML

            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + host + ";DATABASE=" + banco + ";UID=" + usuario + "; PWD=" + senha + ";");

                conexao.Open();

                    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conexao);
                    SqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();

                        Response.Write("<table border='1'>");

                            for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                Response.Write("<th>" + dr.GetName(i) + "</th>");
                            }

                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                Response.Write("<tr>");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                                    {
                                        Response.Write("<td align='center'>" + dr.GetValue(i) + "</td>");
                                    }
                                Response.Write("</tr>");
                            }
                        Response.Write("</table>");

                    dr.Close();
                    dr.Dispose();
                    comando.Dispose(); 

                conexao.Close();
                conexao.Dispose();

        }
    </script>
```

O que eu preciso é que ao abrir a página HTML eu visualize abaixo de tudo, as informações vindas desses script que seriam o número e o arquivo referentes ao número daquela fatura. Sendo que esse nome do arquivo será um link para abrir um anexo (pdf, txt, etc) que estará numa pasta do meu servidor de aplicações.

Eu preciso ter essa página/aplicação distinta?
Como faço para pegar determinado campo html na minha consulta ao banco?

Answer (score 1):

Formate sua URL para passar os campos na origem:

```
 < form method="post" action="http:/ / servidor/aplicativo/Pagina.aspx">
<TABLE width="100%" bordercolorlight="#000000" border="1">
<TBODY>
<TR>
  <!--TD style="WIDTH: 112px">
      <P align=left><img border="0" src=!wf_link!images/logo.jpg></P>
  </TD-->
  <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; width: 18%;">
      <img style="width:auto; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; height:auto;" src=!wf_link!images/logo.jpg>
  </td>

  <td style="WIDTH: 866px; TEXT-ALIGN: center">
      <p><font size="3"><b>SOLICITAÇÃO DE COMPRAS Nr. %NUMSC% (Filial %FILIAL%)</b></font> // campo que preciso obter na minha consulta ao banco
          <input type="hidden" name="NumeroCompra" value="%NUMSC%" />
          <input type="hidden" name="Filial" value="%FILIAL%" />
  </td>

  <td style="WIDTH: 300px">
      <dl>
          <div align="left">
              <dt><font><b>Cód. Aprov.:</b></font>
                  <FONT color=#000000 face="Verdana">
                      <SPAN class=style7 style="font-weight: 400">%CAMPO2%</span>
                      <input type="hidden" name="CodAprov" value="%CAMPO2%" />
                  </FONT>
              </dt>
              <dd>
              <dt><b><font align="left">Nome:</font></b>
                  <FONT color=#000000 face="Verdana">
                      <SPAN class=style7 style="font-weight: 400">%CAMPO3%</span>
                      <input type="hidden" name="Nome" value="%CAMPO3%" />
                  </FONT>
              </dt>
          </div>
      </dl>
  </td>

  </TR>
 <  /  TABLE >
 < / form>
```

E no Seu Forml_Load capture este campo

```
var Compra = Request.Form["NumeroCompra"];
var Filial = Request.Form["Filial"];
```

Comment: Desculpa @FernandoNomellini, não entendi. Como passar os campos pela url? Eu preciso obter um número vindo do html e pegar ele no where da consulta do sql, como aplico sua resposta a isso?

Comment: Seu html tem um FORM ? Se sim, os campos devem estar em <input s> no form e ai no lugar de Request.QueryString["Nome"] você usaria Request.Form["Nome"]

Comment: Não tem nada pronto que permita **extrair** um valor de um html. Você passa valores ou por QueryStrings ou por Forms. Fora isso, você deve buscar uma solução em outro nível, mais complexo.

Comment: Não é um form não... é só essa table mesmo que passei. No caso eu teria que editar meu html para ele virar um form?

Comment: Se você puder editar o HTML para virar FORM, ai sim ficaria fácil.

Comment: no actin do form você indica seu site asp.net exemplo <form method=post action=http: / / meuserver/aplicacao/pagina.aspx> <input type hidden value = "valor1" name = "campo1"> </form>

Comment: mas no caso esse html é um template que gera outros htmls cada um com o número correspondente da compra na qual é obtido pela variável %NUMSC%. Esse template recebe esse número de um banco de dados e gera o html final. Mesmo assim eu consigo aplicar o form - input? Porque não é um campo de inserção manual

Comment: Mudei minha resposta

Comment: Então o meu html é que vai apontar para minha página asp e não o contrário? no meu html eu só preciso colocar no topo a referencia ao scritp asp.net que passei na pergunta? o que no caso voce chamou de Pagina.aspx ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24966/discussion-between-fernandonomellini-and-pfvictor).